# Qual a melhor forma de manipular horários usando python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

tenho um trabalho da faculdade para fazer, onde precisarei criar um código em python que permita o usuário agendar horários para uso de salas da instituição, porém não sei uma forma funcional de manipulação de horários utilizando python, se puderem ajudar fico muito grato!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O módulo [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), que vem por padrão no Python, é um dos melhores que eu já usei pra manipulação de data, hora e intervalos de tempo.

Comment: Muito obrigado, dei uma olhada e realmente creio que possa usá-lo para sanar o problema, vou estudar mais sobre ele.